# Data Structure which supports Multiple keys for search application

Tags: java

I have a table in this way with the columns suppose firstname, lastname and emailid.

I want to implement a java code which uses a data structure to store the respective firstname,lastname and emailid as keys.

Based on this structure a search has to be performed using a string which may coincide with either of the three columns and all the three respective values should be returned i.e. if i enter a lastname then it has to return the respective firstname, lastname and emailid.

I have used SimpleDataObject to store the firstname, lastname and emailid and inserted the objects into a Hashmap.

I have used the below code for my functioning:

```
HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>;
SimpleDataObject sbdoTemp= new SimpleDataObject();
sbdoTemp.setAttribute("FIRST NAME", firstName);
sbdoTemp.setAttribute("LAST NAME",lastName);
sbdoTemp.setAttribute("EMAIL_ADDRESS",emaidId);
map.add(sbdoTemp);
```

Using this method i have to get each attribute and compare the search string.

Is there any alternative which can support multiple keys so that the firstname, lastname and emailId can be set as keys according to which an easy key search can be performed ??

Comment: Try it first yourself and post code, then we will help.

Comment: post what you already tried

Comment: I am using a hashmap to solve the problem but it does not support for multiple keys.
If any other data structure could be used which supports storage in multiple key form and which also helps a quick search in less time.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

You can efficiently implement a searchable data structure using `Map` classes; e.g. `HashMap` or `TreeMap` ... depending on your requirements.  Use a different map for each column.